# Textblock not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I has a UserControl in my application WPF, but i use it textblock "tBlockLunarDay" not show when everything is normal. I'm tried to fix but i can't. can you help me how to fix it?

My userControls

```
<UserControl x:Class="CalendarPlus.ControlCalendar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CalendarPlus"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="60" Loaded="ControlCalendar_OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="7">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Canvas>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tBlockDay" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Width="30" Height="30" Padding="0" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="3" Foreground="AliceBlue">5</TextBlock>
                </Canvas>

                <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ZIndex="99" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tBlockLunarDay" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="1" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True">19</TextBlock>
                </Canvas>

                <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
                    <Image x:Name="imgStar" Width="15" Height="15" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Right="3" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Star512.png"></Image>
                </Canvas>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

i can't upload mostly code so please sympathize for this inconvenience. and this is the code in .CS file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GI-3BIYsqh5IFFTIMY3ubFFxscQT4Ei6

Comment: Are you sure it is invisible ? It most probably in there, but due to forecolor "AntiqueWhite", the visibility isn't great. Try using a different color.  Btw, why do you need those Canvases ?

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to wrap each element in a Canvas. If you want to offset their positions, just set their Margin property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and you just need to change the colour of the text, I couldn't see the "AntiqueWhite" text either.

Also not sure if it's intentional but if you're using canvases to layout the textboxes, you can just set their positions inside the textbox tag like below.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tBlockLunarDay" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="1" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True">19</TextBlock>
```